# GCP Load balancer "failed_to_connect_to_backend" for concurrent requests

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have recently moved to GCP Load balancer from nginx. With nginx I never failed issue of **"failed to connect to backend"**. After moving from nginx to GCP Load Balancer I have started getting multiple occurances of 502 error which is either **connection timed out** or **failed to connect to backend**. With similar backend services when I was using nginx I never faced this issue.

502 Error is very common in context of GCP Load Balancer I believe and there are lots of mentioning on internet about this but none of them has helped me resolved this issue.

Following is the screenshot of few occurances from logs which I have gathered from GCP Load Balancer logs. This issue of failing for concurrent requests was never the case with nginx.

[image]

If anyone could guide me resolve this issue that would be great help.

Comment: Have you checked this doc https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/troubleshooting-ext-https-lbs ?

Answer (score 0):

Load balancers are meant to handle multiple requests. So using Load balancers to handle multiple connections depends on your architecture. If you have multiple backends, you have to use a load balancer; if you are using a single backend, then your web server will do the job.

The 502 error message can be related to several things, here are a few from [Google's page](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#what_is_logged):

backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client
backend_early_response_with_non_error_status
backend_interim_response_not_supported
backend_response_corrupted
backend_response_headers_too_long
backend_timeout
failed_to_connect_to_backend
Failed_to_pick_backend

In order to try to fix the 502 message, you will need to use the values that Google mentions in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#timeouts_and_retries) to configure Keep-alive timeouts for common web server software like Apache and Nginx.

Comment: In order to get a more detailed approach I would suggest to have the following information: 
Where the error originated (on the application side, on the GCE side, another originator? Where did the logs come from? Is there more information regarding the 502 error?